# How can I add a react component to a simple webpage made up of HTML and CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I would like to create a simple webpage that shows a carousel/image gallery that a user can slide through.

A react component that can be used to do this can be found on reactjsexample.com, [here](https://reactjsexample.com/items-carousel-built-with-react-motion-and-styled-components/).

I've gone over the "Add React to a Website" [tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html) but I cannot figure out what JS file I need to edit and save in order to have it be displayed on a webpage.

I have tried adding the the react and react dom development scripts,

And then added the following to the Playground.js file:

```js
ReactDOM.render(e(ItemsCarouselPlayground), document.getElementById('page_contents'));
```

where `page_contents` is a div id in my html page.

However, the carousel still does not appear.

I feel as though adding React components may be much more complicated then as explained in the "Add React to a Website" tutorial.

If someone could help me figure out how to use components from reactjsexample.com, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include any relevant code you have produced so far as a snippet in the body of your question. The HTML page where you are loading the React script tags and any secondary JS files where you are putting your React code would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the tutorial closely, you will find that it builds on top of some "starter code". I outlined the relevant part of the docs in red in the screenshot below.

That said, your Playground.js file should probably look something like this:

```
'use strict';

const e = React.createElement;


// TODO: customise class
class ItemsCarouselPlayground extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { liked: false };
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.liked) {
      return 'You liked this.';
    }

    return e(
      'button',
      { onClick: () => this.setState({ liked: true }) },
      'Like'
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(e(ItemsCarouselPlayground), 
  document.getElementById('page_contents'));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I may suggest the best way to get started with react would be to hop onto the create-react-app bandwagon. This will set everything up for you.

```
npx create-react-app name-of-app
```

Comment: That works of course. But for a beginner, the whole project from that command is in .js. So at least as i write this, the online official tutorial doesn't do it this way. So i can understand the confusion.

Comment: Ahh. Makes sense.